# Apps Script onFormSubmit stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Since last night my script is not functional because the onFormSubmit trigger is not working. Since it was working before and suddenly stopped, I'm guessing it's a problem at google, but I have been changing a lot of things and want to make sure it's not me missing something I did wrong.

Here is the function that creates a form and sets up the trigger:

```
function newForm(ss)
{
  var scriptProperties, form, id, url;
  scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  form = FormApp.create('Form');
  form.setConfirmationMessage('Thanks!');
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss);
  form.setShowLinkToRespondAgain(false);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Name').setRequired(true);
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Email').setRequired(true);
  id = form.getId();
  url = form.getPublishedUrl();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('FORM_ID', id);
  scriptProperties.setProperty('FORM_URL', url);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('bookSlot')
  .forForm(id)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

  return id;
}
```

Here is the function that's supposed to run onFormSubmit:

```
function bookSlot(e)
{
  Logger.log('this');
  var scriptProperties, itemResponses, response, name, email, formChoice, index;
  scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  response = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  name = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  email = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  formChoice = JSON.parse(scriptProperties.getProperty('FORM_CHOICE'));
  index = formChoice.indexOf(response);
  Logger.log('index is ' + index);
}
```

The trigger itself is created when I check in Project's Triggers, seems as if everything should be in place, but nothing is happening when I submit the form. I started getting 'Summary of failures' emails with 'Exceeded maximum execution time' error for the bookSlot() with the formSubmit trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The script will stop working if the quotas are exceeded. You can find all the quotas in this link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas